# Redirecting process file and folder access without hooking

Tags: windows, winapi

Windows can redirect folder access as seen with the WOW64 [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [Desktop Bridge file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#file-system). Can any application similarly instruct the OS to redirect an arbitrary folder for a child (or other) process or is this ability only available to the OS itself?

I'm aware this can be simulated by injecting code into the process (e.g. with hooking) to intercept reads and writes, however I'm asking if there is an api that makes use of Window's own file system features.

Comment: I believe this is possible using a file system filter driver.

Comment: If this was userspace stuff that anyone could use, it would be insanely exploitable. Injection/hooking at least requires debug privledge to patch the pages. A file system filter driver as the above comment says would work as well, but perhaps you could look at it from a different angle...? This is extreme. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to partially isolate some programs from the real file system, preferably in a way that is robust and secure. I think a minifilter driver may be the way to go.

Comment: Depending on your circumstances, something like [this product](https://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) might be useful to you.  (I've never used it myself, so I make no promises!)